# Counting Python Regex Matches Efficiently

Tags: python, regex, performance, re2

I need to efficiently counter Python Regex matches. Findall and finditer works, but are slow for **large** number of searches.

So far I have this (much simplified version):

```
import re
testItem = re.compile(r"var")
for matches in testItem.finditer(stringData):
    counter = counter + 1
return counter
```

I am running multiple instances of this method. I do not care for the matches themselves; I simply wish to return the counter.

The issue is that the stringData is a very large string. The Regex itself is pretty simple.

Please advise on a more efficient way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the regex for a single string quick? Is it significantly slower for long strings?

Comment: `sum(testItem.finditer(stringData))`

Comment: The problem is that the string is very very long. That's why it's slow. The regex itself is simple.

Comment: Can you include the regex?

Comment: Done. It's very simple. Merely finding characters 'var' in a string.

Comment: I have other instances of the same function with more complex Regex. Substring would work for this but not others. Even so, the performance does not improve with substring extraction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you show in your edit that you're just looking for a substring,

```
stringData.count('var')
```

should serve you well.

Of course, this does not generalize to many other uses of REs!  Unfortunately, at least as of Python 3.4, `re.finditer` returns an iterator which does not support the "length hint" formalized by [PEP 424](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/), so there aren't many good alternatives (for the general case) to

```
sum(1 for _ in there.finditer(stringData))
```

Comment: No difference in performance. Ran it using timeit with 10 iterations. Regex was 2.437s, substring was 2.64s.